# Countable $T_2$-spaces that are invariant under point removal

Tags: general-topology

Let's call a $T_2$-space $(X,\tau)$ **invariant under point removal** if for every $x\in X$ we have $X \cong (X\setminus\{x\})$ where $X\setminus\{x\}$ is endowed with the subspace topology.

Examples of countable Hausdorff spaces that are invariant under point removal include

- $(\mathbb{N},\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N}))$;
- possibly (I'm not quite sure now, have to think about it more) $\mathbb{Q}$ with the topology inherited from the Euclidean topology on $\mathbb{R}$;

Are there any other examples?

Comment: How about the disjoint union of your examples?

Comment: Right -- now actually I'm not sure whether $\mathbb{Q}$ is an example indeed.

Comment: On a tangential note, the only countable Hausdorff space homeomorphic to each of its infinite subspaces is the countable discrete space. See R. Bonnet, *On superatomic Boolean algebras*, Finite and infinite combinatorics in sets and logic (Banff, AB, 1991), *NATO Adv. Sci. Inst. Ser. C Math. Phys. Sci.* **411**, Dordrecht: Kluwer Acad. Publ., 31–62,

Comment: To see that $\mathbb Q$ is invariant under point removal: (1) the subspace topology on a dense subset of $\mathbb R$ is the same as the order topology of the subset, and (2) any countable dense linear order without endpoints is order-isomorphic to $\mathbb Q$ (Cantor), so in particular $\mathbb Q$ minus a point is order-isomorphic to $\mathbb Q$. (And of course for the same reason all countable dense subsets of $\mathbb R$ are homeomorphic.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $X$ be a countable Hausdorff space. Consider $Y$ to be the disjoint union of all $X\setminus F$ where $F$ is a finite set $F\subset X$.